# Script that Show which hdisks each of the filesystems reside on for IBM AIX

Tags: shell-script, ksh, aix

i have the folowing script that Show which hdisks each of the filesystems reside on for IBM AIX.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
for vg in `lsvg -o`; do 
    for fs in `lsvgfs $vg`; do 
      printf "%-22s" $fs; 
      for disk in `lsvg -p $vg | tail +3 | awk '{print $1}'`; do 
          lspv -l $disk | grep -q " ${fs}$" && printf "%-8s" $disk; 
      done; 
      echo 
   done; 
done
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1hdisk189hdisk200hdisk146hdisk151hdisk136hdisk141 
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2hdisk188hdisk201hdisk144hdisk152hdisk137hdisk191
```

first the output won't show up correctly as it should be like this:

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1 hdisk189 hdisk200 hdisk146 hdisk151 hdisk136 hdisk141 
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2 hdisk188 hdisk201 hdisk144 hdisk152 hdisk137 hdisk191
```

and i need to upgrade it to see the total space of the disk and the used space by the file system in every one of them something like

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1 hdisk189 hdisk200 hdisk146 hdisk151 hdisk136 hdisk141 
                               1000g 2000g 1000g 1000g 3000g 1000g 
                                 300g   500g   250g  90g   80g   30g 
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2 hdisk188 hdisk201 hdisk144 hdisk152 hdisk137 hdisk191 
                               1000g 2000g 1000g 1000g 3000g 1000g 
                                 300g    500g  250g   90g  80g  30g
```

in this example the fs /apps/data/IAMV1/sys1 uses 300g from hdisk189 and so on ... to be honest i don't know how to do that i know i can have the total space of the disk using this

```
getconf DISK_SIZE /dev/hdisk189
```

thanks Everyone.

Comment: Since filesystems (on LV's) can span multiple disks, what do you think of `lspv -l` on the various disks? The PP size combined with the LP's would give you the space used per LV, per PV.

Comment: Hey, I [recognize that script](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/show_which_hdisk_s_each_of_your_filesystems_reside_on_for_aix1?lang=en#threadid=c89f7097-ff0d-459d-b1a7-d5d62f4a6145)! Fun to see a script suggestion from 6 years ago come back, only to see the [whole site being retired in circa 3 days from now](https://developer.ibm.com/code/dw-connections-sunset-faq/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered in another post.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412240/script-that-show-which-hdisks-each-of-the-filesystems-reside-on-for-ibm-aix)

Thank you everyone for the help and support